# How to get the JSON string representation of a sencha store?

Tags: json, sencha-touch-2

I need to convert a sencha store object to a JSON string; the store has a model which contain another collection of models.
The way I'm doing it is concatenating strings as per below:
I do Ext.JSON.encode(getData()) of the parent model, then 
I loop through the child nodes and get the Ext.JSON.encode(getData()) of them, it works but don't think is the best way to do it.
Cheers,
H

Comment: provide a sample of your store code it will help us to solve your query asap, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for the [getAssociatedData()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-getAssociatedData) method?

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid that's not available for sencha touch, just Ext.js

Comment: I have found that it works in sencha touch so I'm marking this as the best answer